# How to add column using execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I just want to add column using execute immediate but  I am getting an error.  Please let me know the this PL/SQL block is correct or not?

```
create or replace procedure add_column (xyz in varchar2, abc in varchar2) is
begin 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || 'xyz add abc varchar2(20)';
    dbms_output.put_line('New column added');
end;

exec add_column ('students', 'time');

error: Error starting at line : 8 in command -
BEGIN add_column ('students', 'time'); END;

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "HR.ADD_COLUMN", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string concatanation as:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || xyz || ' add ' || abc || ' varchar2(20)';
```

Also, `DBMS_ASSERT` can be used to check for the valid names of the table and column as follows.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || sys.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(xyz) 
                   || ' add ' || sys.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(abc) || ' varchar2(20)';
```

Here, `xyz` and `abc` will be replaced with the input parameter names.

Comment: Done. Thank you so much for your help. :)